# Formatted windows 10 original while installing ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, ubuntu-20.04, dualboot

I had windows 10 installed on my lenovo l340 .i tried to dual boot my laptop with ubuntu 20.04. but while dual booting it did an error by which linux took swap area from ssd where windows was installed .So when I tried to boot windows 10 it was unable to boot. now my ubuntu is running. But it is unable to access  partitions of hard disk other than allocated to it. so what should I do now to get my data back and reinstall windows.
plzz help !!

Comment: You reinstall Windows by booting to a Windows installation disk.  As for data recovery, it’s probably to late for that, since data recovery requires the data NOT be overwritten and those most certainly has happen if it’s being overwritten by the swap

Comment: Alternatively, recover from your backup. You **do** have a backup, don't you? No-one would attempt this kind of task without one...